# add data into dataString and pass it into ajax data

Tags: jquery

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".check").click(function(){
        $("input:checkbox[class=check]:checked").each(function () {
            //alert($(this).val());
            //alert($(this).attr("id"));
            var key = $(this).val();
            var value = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(key'='+value);

            //alert(value); 
            //var dataString = key='+'value;
            //alert(dataString);

        });
        //alert(dataString);
    });
});
</script>
```

Shown above is my code and I want to pass a string into ajax data in the format of key=value and receive it into php $_POST['key'] variable

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: dataString,
cache: false,
dataType: "html",
```

Please anybody tell me how I can do this. The problem is concatenating data into dataString too.

Comment: you can try like `data: {"key" : dataString},`

Comment: vijay i want add multiple check box  into dataString in which check box id work like key and value work like value and after that i can pass it into ajax data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
var key   = $(this).val(),
    value = $(this).attr("id"),
    dataString = {};
    dataString[key] = value;
```

As ajax `data` properties can accept object like `{ key : value, key : value,.... }`

**Updated.**

Seems like you could't able to catch up the example, here i made example for you,
Suppose this is our HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a" id="aa" checked/>a
<input type="checkbox" value="a1" id="aaa" checked/>a1
<input type="checkbox" value="a2" id="aaaa" checked/>a2
<input type="checkbox" value="a3" id="aaaaa" />a3
<button>Click</button>
```

And this is our JS :

```
$('button').click(function () {
  // this must be define on the outside of each
  var dataString = {};
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {
    var key = $(this).val();
    var value = $(this).attr('id');
    dataString[key] = value;
  });
  // open console to see the actual result
  console.log(dataString);
  // here you can make ajax request and use
  // dataString as parameter like your current code
});
```

This is expected result `Object {a: "aa", a1: "aaa", a2: "aaaa"}`, and here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/10nmu3f2/)

And later on in PHP page, just retrieve it by :

```
$_POST['a']; // <-- aa
$_POST['a1']; // <-- aaa
$_POST['a2']; // <-- aaaa
```

Comment: noril i want to add values into data string first and after that it pass into ajax data

Comment: Yes, as you loop over checked checbox, then it will insert the different keys and values based on iterated element

Comment: working but I don't understand how to pass tha data in ajax $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: dataString,
cache: false,
dataType: "html",

Comment: I dont have enough reputation for chat can u please give your skype id norlihazmey

Comment: opss, didt have. What you actually done right now are correct